# Adding citations to Lyx document?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I haven't used any `*.bib` file. I need help with citations in Lyx.

1. How can I put references to Lyx document?
2. How can I put my references in to `insert->citation` window without using any bibliography?

**My demonstration about citations in Lyx**

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Accept a correct answer

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you use BibTeX (or another manager). But if you want to input them directly, in LyX go to the environment dropdown (e.g. in a new document it says "Standard"). Click on it and choose "Bibliography" (it might be the last option). For a keyboard shortcut, do alt + p,  and then start typing "bibliography" to filter the dropdown list. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you look at this [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299312/biblatex-biber-and-lyx-how-to-resolve-bibliographystyle-error) about biblatex, biber err in Lyx. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

@scottkosty's answer is correct to your question, but as he already mentioned, there is a more efficient and flexible way to create the references table then you asked for.

The BibTeX-file can be easily generated by software like JabRef, Mendeley, Zotero or simply an ASCII editor. Very convenient is that most journals and even some libraries offer to download the correct BibTeX citation for each article or book they offer. In the end, you can easily recycle the BibTeX file of references.

In order to include the BibTeX-file, choose from the menu "Insert" -> "List/TOC" -> "BibTeX Bibliography ...". Then in the popup menu, click "Add..." and then "Browse..." to navigate to the BibTeX-file.

Comment: Answer to part 1 of the question +1, this I find more efficient even though less accessible (not so visible).

Comment: Any experience in Biber and Lyx? Perhaps you know answer to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299312/biblatex-biber-and-lyx-how-to-resolve-bibliographystyle-error)?